# jQuery next sibling that has a particular kind of child

Tags: jquery, siblings, arrow-keys

My HTML has a container element with many sibling `div` elements, each of which contains a `contenteditable` `p`. These sibling `div` are "interrupted", however, by other `div` which do not contain an editable element.

What is challenging me at the moment is how to "hop over" these interrupting `div` when using the left and right arrow keys to move from C to D or from D back to C (see snippet). Navigation stops when it encounters these `div` lacking an editable element. How can I correct this?

```js
$('#foo p[contenteditable = "true"]').bind("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      var $P = $(this).parent().prev().children('p[contenteditable = "true"]');
      setTimeout(() => $P.focus(), 0);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;

    case "ArrowRight":
      var $P = $(this).parent().next().children('p[contenteditable = "true"]');
      setTimeout(() => $P.focus(), 0);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#foo p[contenteditable="true"] {
  /* font-size: 22px;*/
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#foo p.const {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

#foo div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"></p>
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="1"></p>
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"></p>
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">"</p>
    <p>"</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"></p>
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"></p>
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `prev()` or `next()`, use `.prevAll(":has(p[contenteditable])").first()` and `.nextAll(":has(p[contenteditable])").first()`:

```js
$('#foo p[contenteditable = "true"]').bind("keydown", function(e) {

  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      var $P = $(this).parent().prevAll(":has(p[contenteditable])").first().children('p[contenteditable = "true"]');
      setTimeout(() => $P.focus(), 0);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;

    case "ArrowRight":
      var $P = $(this).parent().nextAll(":has(p[contenteditable])").first().children('p[contenteditable = "true"]');
      setTimeout(() => $P.focus(), 0);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;

  }

});
```

```css
#foo p[contenteditable="true"] {
  /* font-size: 22px;*/
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#foo p.const {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

#foo div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">

  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"></p>
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="1"></p>
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"></p>
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;
      <p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">"</p>
    <p>"
      <p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"></p>
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"></p>
    <p>E</p>
  </div>



</div>
```

[`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)/[`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) match all previous/following siblings that match the selector, returning a jQuery object *in order* (so the nearest sibling is first, then the second nearest, etc.); using `.first()` then reduces the set to just the nearest sibling.

I've used the [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-selector in that, but you might be better off giving the relevant elements a class instead, since `:has` is a jQuery-specific addition to CSS. Here I've used the class `stop` so it's `.xxxxAll(".stop").first()`:

```js
$('#foo p[contenteditable = "true"]').bind("keydown", function(e) {

  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      var $P = $(this).parent().prevAll(".stop").first().children('p[contenteditable = "true"]');
      setTimeout(() => $P.focus(), 0);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;

    case "ArrowRight":
      var $P = $(this).parent().nextAll(".stop").first().children('p[contenteditable = "true"]');
      setTimeout(() => $P.focus(), 0);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      break;

  }

});
```

```css
#foo p[contenteditable="true"] {
  /* font-size: 22px;*/
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#foo p.const {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

#foo div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">

  <div class="stop">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"></p>
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stop">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="1"></p>
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stop">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"></p>
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;
      <p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">"</p>
    <p>"
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="stop">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"></p>
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stop">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"></p>
    <p>E</p>
  </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you need to use `prevAll()` and `nextAll()`, instead of `prev()` and `next()`, as there's intermediary elements which you need to skip. You can combine this the `:has()` selector to only find containers which have a descendent `contenteditable` and also with `first()` to retrieve the nearest match.

Also note that `bind()` is deprecated and will be removed from jQuery soon; use `on()` instead. The logic can also be amended slightly to reduce the reliance on `switch` and avoid the unnecessary repetition. Finally you have used `<p>` instead of `</p>` in a couple of places in the HTML.

With that said, try this:

```js
let keyMethodLookup = {
  ArrowLeft: 'prevAll',
  ArrowRight: 'nextAll'
}

$('#foo p[contenteditable="true"]').on("keydown", e => {
  if (!keyMethodLookup.hasOwnProperty(e.key))
    return;

  let method = keyMethodLookup[e.key];
  $(e.currentTarget).parent()[method]('div:has(p[contenteditable="true"])').first().children('p[contenteditable="true"]').focus();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#foo p[contenteditable="true"] {
  /* font-size: 22px;*/
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#foo p.const {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

#foo div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"></p>
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="1"></p>
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"></p>
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">"</p>
    <p>"</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"></p>
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"></p>
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me some new ways to use javascript.